# Why does water sometimes split into H+ OH- (H3O* OH-)?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I am aware that this isnt the water splitting into H+ and OH-, and that is is just a transfer of Hydrogen via autoionisation ...

(found this on here: [Why does water split into ions?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82927/why-does-water-split-into-ions) //
"Water does not really split into ions. It transfers protons, reversibly, from one molecule to another:
2H2O = H3O+ + OH−
The ions represent, of course, a less stable state than molecular water, at least under ordinary conditions, so the equilibrium constant is low. Yet this reaction strongly affects the chemical prpoeryies and even some physical properties of aqueous solutions." )

...but I want to know why it is that this happens, as Kw is very small 10^-14, this doesnt happen much, but I wish to find an explaination for why this actually happens, what causes the hydrogen to be transfered to another water molecule?

Thank you to anyone who gets back to me!

Comment: This should be covered in physical chemistry under statistical thermodynamics. Have you learnt those?

Comment: I'm not sure what explanation would you what. Water is both slightly acidic and basic, and that's the result.

Comment: You mere ask why acids sometimes provide a proton and why bases sometimes accept a proton.